# How to extract Work Breakdown Structure Level 3 descriptor in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to get my 3rd level WBS structure returned in excel regardless of character length.

Specific examples: if my WBS is 1.2.3.1, I want to return 1.2.3 and if my WBS is 1.200.4.2, I want to return 1.200.4. In other words, character length between periods does not matter.

I was using `LEFT()` but this does not take into account character length. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that all you need to do is remove the third "." and any characters that follow it. In that case, and assuming the WBS string is in cell A1, you can use

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(".",A1,SEARCH(".",A1,SEARCH(".",A1)+1)+1)-1)
```

If A1 contains "1.200.4.2", this will return "1.200.4".

Answer (score 1):

This formula will extract the WBS Level 3 descriptor from the full descriptor stored in `A1`:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","~",3))-1)
```

Note that this formula can be adapted to extract *any* level descriptor. Just replace the `3` with the level required.

For example, to extract the Level 2 descriptor, use:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","~",2))-1)
```

Also note that this formula will return an error if a descriptor which is already Level 3 is supplied. The following allows for this:

```
=
IFERROR(
  LEFT(A1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","~",3))-1),
  IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",".",2),NA())
)
```

---

Another formula you may find useful is this:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","~",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))-0))-1)
```

It returns an ancestor level. Note that this formula is also multi-level. To return the ancestor two levels up replace the `-0` with `-1`. For three levels up, use `-2`, etc.